# regex for pattern in grep

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to look for gene symbols in some text, for that purpose I am trying to establish a pattern that matches gene symbols (they use to be three or more uppercase letters together). I tried this but it didn't work.

```
TW2 <- text_words [grep ("b\[[:upper:]]b\", text_words) ]
```

Comment: Looks like R, try `TW2 <- unlist(regmatches(text_words, gregexpr("\\b[[:upper:]]{3,}\\b", text_words)))`

Comment: FWIW, it's not necessary to use regex (and for performance may be good to have more than one option). Another option would be to split the sentence into a list of words, and check if each word is 3+ characters, and check if each word was the same upper case as original, and check if each word is contains at least 1 letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
text_words <- "GHJ GJKGKJ HHKKK J777 JJ8JJJJ"
TW2 <- unlist(regmatches(text_words, gregexpr("\\b[[:upper:]]{3,}\\b", text_words)))
TW2
## => [1] "GHJ"    "GJKGKJ" "HHKKK"
```

See the [R demo online](http://rextester.com/CRROXY51084)

The pattern matches:

- `\\b`  - a word boundary
- `[[:upper:]]{3,}` - 3 or more uppercase letters
- `\\b`  - a word boundary.

If you have a vector with the strings you need to test against the pattern in full, use

```
text_words <- c("GHJ","GJKGKJ","HHKKK","J777","JJ8JJJJ")
TW2 <- grep("^[[:upper:]]{3,}$", text_words, value=TRUE)
TW2
## => [1] "GHJ"    "GJKGKJ" "HHKKK"
```

Here, word boundaries are replaced with anchors, `^` for the start of the string and `$` for the end of the string. See [another R demo](http://rextester.com/HZWHU12224).